# How to refresh the data table after data appended

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to refresh the data table after data appended

```
List results = [];
  DataRow _getDataRow(index, data) {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(results[index]['item_code'])),//add name of your columns here
        DataCell(Text(results[index]['item_name'])),
        DataCell(Text(results[index]['rate'])),
        DataCell(Text("10")),//add name of your columns here
        DataCell(Text("here")),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the function named `_getDataRow` is a template for the actual objects which will be invoked in the page, so you need to call it and use any state management to update the content, I suggest to use [bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) or [provider](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Answer (score 0):

While a state management using for example [BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc;) should be preferred,
for quick testing you can use the setState argument inside of a StatefulWidget like this...

```
    setState(() {
       results = _getDataRow(someIndex, newData);
    });
```